# How to stop firestore from auto creating sub collections based on dash?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Flutter code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("EventsByDate")
    .doc("06-15-2020").set({
      "name": "Flutter Demo Day",
      "venue": "Javits center"
    });
```

Creates a document "06" in collection "EventsByDate".
Document "06" contains a sub-collection "15".
"15" contains a sub-collection "2020".
"2020" contains the data I am setting!

How do I stop firebase/firestore from creating this sub-collection hierarchical structure?

All I want is a document "06-15-2020" which contains the data I am setting. Don't want any of these subcollections!

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: could you share example data on what you are setting and the `{...}` portion of your code

Comment: Sure @SoniSol - here is a sample: https://gist.github.com/ajaygautam/d6367d64353dbc3074e2919bf9167e02

Comment: hi @Ajay a Good practice in stack overflow is to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within the question so it is self-contained and doesn´t depend on external resources

Comment: The contents of {...} are irrelevant here. The issue here is on the "key"... which has full data. PS: A minimal reproducible example would actually be a git repo, which would be an overkill for this question.

Comment: @AjayGautam as Soni mentioned it is expected from the poster to add enough information so the issue can be replicated so basically no reproducible example -> no reproduction -> no help can be given -> no answer to the question

Comment: Ok guys. I have updated the question to contain the data as well. Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thanks.

Comment: which version of the client library are you using?

Comment: Using library: cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3

Comment: this seems an issue under the library and it is already reported on its gihub  https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4498